# How do I move the dock to the left side of the middle screen in a 3 monitor setup?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, dock

I can only move it to the far left or far right.

I found a third party program that will create a new dock and place it on the inside edges of monitors, but it only handles shortcuts, applications and folders.

I want my open programs to be on the left side of the middle monitor.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered by [3 Monitors in a row and I want the dock in the middle](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/217468) (probably/possibly you) on AskDifferent, StackExchange's Apple-specific forum.

[My favorite answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/395365) is a slight hack, but with minimized downside. Essentially,

1. On System Preferences > Arrangement of Displays, put the middle monitor virtually on the left: [Arrangement of Displays .jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2OYh.png)
2. Set System Preferences > Dock > Position on screen = Left.

That will put your dock on the left side of your middle monitor. The only downside is that you have to remember to get to your leftmost monitor, you have to move the mouse up to the top of the middle monitor.

Unfortunately, at this time, Mac doesn't have the innate capability to have the dock on the left side of a virtually middle monitor.